# VS2012: Ctrl+F now synchronizes with Ctrl+Shft+F

Tags: visual-studio-2012, replace, resharper

In Visual Studio 2012, I want different context for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. However, when I enter data in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> dialog (in the upper right corner of the text editor), it synchronizes that information to the dialog shown by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. I don't want that. I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to do a search in the Entire Solution for now and forever. How can I disconnect these dialogs? I'm using Resharper 7.1 and VSCommands11, if that changes things.

(And why does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> take three seconds to show the dialog in the upper right corner? It bugs me when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and start typing only to find that it changes my source file.)

Answer (score 1):

Open the options-window. (Tools->Options). In the tree on the left side select Environmend->Keyboard. There are two entries relevant for you:

- *Edit.Find* is for the Search-Box at the right upper corner (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- *Edit.FindinFiles* is for the SearchDialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

Maybe any of your VisualStudio-Extension has set these Commands to other commands.

In my studio both searches are separated from each other. If I set *Entire Solution* in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shif</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>-Dialog, that does not affect the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>-Dialog

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce the behavior I was seeing last week. My keyboard shortcuts are correct. I think what may have been throwing me off is that Ctrl+F3 searches in selection if that was the last scope. I expect Ctrl+F3/F3 to scope to current document rather than the last selected scope in the Ctrl+F window.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: `Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard` > click `reset button`

Comment: Wouldn't this reset all the Resharper-installed keyboard shortcuts?